# UPDATE a Decimal Value (SQL Server) through Mule using JDBC

Tags: string, jdbc, type-conversion, mule, decimal

I have this issue when I try to update a DECIMAL value through Database Connector Update Statement in Mule Runtime 3.8.5

```
org.mule.api.MessagingException: The conversion from String to DECIMAL is unsupported. (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException).
```

The simple code that is failing is:

```
UPDATE Faults SET STATUS=1 where FAULT_ID=#[flowVars.faultId]
```

The STATUS field is of type DECIMAL(1,0).
I've also tried to SET STATUS=1.0, but it throws the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: what is FAULT_ID? is it decimal or string ? are you setting SET STATUS=1 hardcoded in sql query or using any flowvar? what is the working sql query ?

Comment: FAULT_ID is a String. But thats not the problem, I've updated another values (char, date, ...) with fault_id as a where condition.

Comment: I'm hardcoding SET STATUS=1 in a Parametrized SQL query inside db connector (inside a mule flow, of course)

Comment: can you try #[1] as parameter and let me know

Comment: Good one. I'm going to try.

Comment: Ok, so the database team changed the datatype value to char(1), so I couldn't test it in that table. Now it's working. Then I chose another table with a identical decimal(1,0) field for Testing purposes, and my original query works without problems...